# How to show a form on a dropdown in angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to show a simple `form` (as shown in image below) as a `dropdown` when an `icon` is clicked. I looked into the component list of angular material but I couldn't find any suitable component for this. There is **[menu](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview)** but that can't be used in this case.

Does someone know how can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: You are probably looking for an overlay: https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview

Comment: Have you looked into expansion-panels? [material expansion panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview)

Comment: Please explain why Menu isn't suitable. Knowing why might help others give you a better answer.

Comment: @G.Tranter Thanks for you comment. It would be great if we could repurpose Menu for this. It tried [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1m3czf?file=app/menu-overview-example.html) as you can see i can see only one input on Menu (instead of 3) and click on input closes the menu.

Comment: @NikolaiKiefer I want form on overlay/dropdown. I dont think expansion panel would fit here.

Answer (score 9):

You can use MatMenu, but you need to do a few things to make it work.

The first is to *not* use `mat-menu-item`. This forces styling on the item so that it has a fixed height of what you would expect for a menu item.

The second is to prevent interaction from propagating back to the menu causing it to close whenever you try to use the form. Use the Event.stopPropagation() function on the outer-most parent of your form inside the menu. You might also want to prevent the menu from closing when you click outside it on the backdrop (and add your own close or cancel button). That will look something like:

```
<mat-menu class="menu-form-wrapper" [hasBackdrop]="false">
  <div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()">
    <form class="menu-form">
    ...
```

You also need to take care of styling issues. Your form container needs to take up the entire menu so that the user can't click outside of it but still on the menu, causing it to close. And you need to override the default padding that MatMenu adds to its `mat-menu-content` container. This style needs to be in your global style sheet, not in the component style, and it is where you will add your form's layout:

```
// override mat-menu-content padding
.menu-form-wrapper .mat-menu-content:not(:empty) {
  padding: 0;
}

// layout for the form
.menu-form-wrapper .menu-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 24px;
}
```

[Here it is on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1m3czf-ztwlvz?file=app%2Fmenu-overview-example.html).

Answer (score 3):

If     **[Menu Api](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api)**    is not helpful in your case,
 then you can use    **[Dialog Api](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api)**    with `updatePosition` and with `hasBackdrop: false`.

- Using `hasBackdrop: false` will not create the overlay.
- Open the dialog next to the button from where you want to show the dropdown.
- **[Demo Opening Dialog at desired location](https://angular-mat-dialog-updated-position.stackblitz.io/)**

**Open Dialog from Component as :**

```
let  dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ExampleDialogComponent, {
        width: '250px',
        data: filterData,
        hasBackdrop: false,
        panelClass: 'filter-popup'
      });
```

**In Dialog Component :**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.filterData = this.data;
    const rightMostPos = window.innerWidth - Number(this.filterData.left);
    this.dialogRef.updatePosition({ top: `${this.filterData.top}px`,
    right: `${rightMostPos}px`});
  }
```

**Application Code :** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog-updated-position?file=app%2Fexample%2Fexample-dialog%2Fexample-dialog.component.ts